Hiding/Removing the secondary y-axis
The script below creates a line chart. I want to hide the secondary y-axis. To be precise, I do not want to show the axis, but like a legend that explains the color of the lines.
Is there a different way to scale the "by new customers" percentage values? I also do not want to use "fold".
{ "autosize":"fit",
  "title": {"text": "a layered chart using Vega-Lite", "frame": "group"},
  "data": {
        "name": "thedata",
        "values": [
          {"month": "Jan" , "sales": 8000, "by new customers": 0.2},
          {"month": "Feb" , "sales": 8200, "by new customers": 0.21},
          {"month": "Mar" , "sales": 8700, "by new customers": 0.3},
          {"month": "Apr" , "sales": 9000, "by new customers": 0.33},
          {"month": "May" , "sales": 10000, "by new customers": 0.4},
          {"month": "Jun" , "sales": 11000, "by new customers": 0.41},
          {"month": "Jul" , "sales": 11200, "by new customers": 0.38},
          {"month": "Aug" , "sales": 12000, "by new customers": 0.36},
          {"month": "Sep" , "sales": 13000, "by new customers": 0.32},
          {"month": "Oct" , "sales": 13400, "by new customers": 0.28},
          {"month": "Nov" , "sales": 13800, "by new customers": 0.2},
          {"month": "Dec" , "sales": 1000, "by new customers": 0.2}
        ]
    },
    "repeat": {
    "layer": ["sales", "by new customers"]
    },
    "spec": {
    "mark": "line",
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
        "field": "month",
        "type": "nominal",
        "sort": 
            ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
      },
      "y": {
        "field": {"repeat": "layer"},
        "type": "quantitative"
      },
      "color": {
        "datum": {"repeat": "layer"},
        "type": "nominal"
      }
    }
  },
  "resolve": {
    "scale": {
      "y": "independent"
      }
  }
}


Davide, if I remove resolve, the percentage value will not be scaled.
I do not want to go to Vega because I create "easier" templates.
I'm currently facing a dilemma. If I don't use repeat, I lose the legend. However, I want the legend without the secondary y-axis.
Currently, I'm using config and axisRight{...}. This looks promising, but then I must look at the distance between the visualization and the legend.

This took me some time,
there is no secondary y-axis, but there is a legend.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I'm using config to "hide" the axisRight, I also use offset in the legend of the color scale to "bridge the space" between the view and the legend.
{ 
  "width": 400,
  "title": {"text": "a layered chart using Vega-Lite", "frame": "group"},

  "data": {
        "name": "thedata",
        "values": [
          {"month": "Jan" , "sales": 8000, "by new customers": 0.2},
          {"month": "Feb" , "sales": 8200, "by new customers": 0.21},
          {"month": "Mar" , "sales": 8700, "by new customers": 0.3},
          {"month": "Apr" , "sales": 9000, "by new customers": 0.33},
          {"month": "May" , "sales": 10000, "by new customers": 0.4},
          {"month": "Jun" , "sales": 11000, "by new customers": 0.41},
          {"month": "Jul" , "sales": 11200, "by new customers": 0.38},
          {"month": "Aug" , "sales": 12000, "by new customers": 0.36},
          {"month": "Sep" , "sales": 13000, "by new customers": 0.32},
          {"month": "Oct" , "sales": 13400, "by new customers": 0.28},
          {"month": "Nov" , "sales": 13800, "by new customers": 0.2},
          {"month": "Dec" , "sales": 1000, "by new customers": 0.2}
        ]
    },
    "repeat": {
      "layer": ["sales", "by new customers"]
    },
    "spec": {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "month",
          "type": "nominal",
          "sort": 
              ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        },
        "y": {
          "field": {"repeat": "layer"},
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {
          "datum": {"repeat": "layer"},
          "scale": {
            "domain": ["sales", "by new customers"],
            "range": ["blue", "orange"]
          },
          "legend": {
              "offset":-15,
             "labelAlign":"left"
          }
        }
      }
  },
  "config": {
    "axisRight": {
      "title":null,
      "titleOpacity": 0,
      "domainOpacity": 0,
      "tickOpacity": 0,
      "labelOpacity": 0
    }
  },
  "resolve": {
    "scale": {"y": "independent"}
  }
}
```
  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/26nkhCSM.png


You can use 2 layers:

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": {"text": "a layered chart using Vega-Lite", "frame": "group"},
  "data": {
    "name": "thedata",
    "values": [
      {"month": "Jan", "sales": 8000, "by new customers": 0.2},
      {"month": "Feb", "sales": 8200, "by new customers": 0.21},
      {"month": "Mar", "sales": 8700, "by new customers": 0.3},
      {"month": "Apr", "sales": 9000, "by new customers": 0.33},
      {"month": "May", "sales": 10000, "by new customers": 0.4},
      {"month": "Jun", "sales": 11000, "by new customers": 0.41},
      {"month": "Jul", "sales": 11200, "by new customers": 0.38},
      {"month": "Aug", "sales": 12000, "by new customers": 0.36},
      {"month": "Sep", "sales": 13000, "by new customers": 0.32},
      {"month": "Oct", "sales": 13400, "by new customers": 0.28},
      {"month": "Nov", "sales": 13800, "by new customers": 0.2},
      {"month": "Dec", "sales": 1000, "by new customers": 0.2}
    ]
  },
  "spacing": 0,
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "height": 200,
      "width": 200,
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "month",
          "type": "nominal",
          "sort": [
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "May",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sep",
            "Oct",
            "Nov",
            "Dec"
          ]
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "line",
          "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "sales", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"value": "blue"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": "line",
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "by new customers",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "labels": false,
                "domain": false,
                "ticks": false,
                "grid": false,
                "title": null
              }
            },
            "color": {"value": "silver"}
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}
    },
    {
      "width": 1,
      "mark": {"type": "bar"},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "Nothing",
          "scale": {
            "domain": ["Sales", "By New Customers"],
            "range": ["blue", "silver"]
          },
          "legend": {
            "title": null,
            "symbolType": "diamond",
            "rowPadding": 8,
            "padding": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


Thank you, but then I lose the legend!

@TomMartens legend added now :)
